# Creating a Function with its own methods

Tags: javascript

I have been following an excellent [guide](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/5328-javascript-data-structures-the-linked-list.html) on linked lists in JS. I encountered a function with 'dot' notation as if it was adding a property or method to the function. I don't know how this works Here is the code snippet. ([repl.it link](http://repl.it/QfJ/2))

```
function List(){
    List.makeNode = function(){
        return {
            data: null,
            next: null
        };
    };
    this.start = null;
    this.end = null;

    this.add = function(data){
        if(this.start === null){
            this.start = List.makeNode();
            this.end = this.start;
        } else {
            this.end.next = List.makeNode();
            this.end = this.end.next;
        }
        this.end.data = data;
    };
}

var list=new List();
```

My question is mainly on line 2:

```
List.makeNode = function(){}
```

Here is the line of text describing what this line of code is doing:

> We also need an easy way to create a node and one possible way is to
>   provide the constructor function List with a makeNode method: If this
>   seems strange to you recall that a function is also an object and can
>   have methods and properties. This approach is similar to providing
>   class or static methods and properties.

I understand the concept of a constructor function.  In my last line of code I invoke the constructor List(); with the new keyword resulting in in var list containing an object:

```
{ start: null, 
  end: null, 
  add: [Function] 
}
```

Furthermore, if I replaced 'List.makeNode'(on line 2 of my List() constructor) with 'this.makeNode...' My var list object I am creating would have the makeNode function as a method on the list object:

```
{ makeNode: [Function], 
  start: null, 
  end: null, 
  add: [Function] 
}
```

I understand List() is ultimately an Object and ultimately inherits everything from Object.prototype.  This List() object/ constructor function contains:

```
{ [Function: List] makeNode: [Function] }
```

I don't really know how this is working.

- Is makeNode a property/method on the List Object which also contains
  the List Function?
- Why do we have to keep makeNode associated with    List?
- Is it a big deal to change List to 'this' and have the    makeNode
  function on every new instance of 'List()'?

I am very lost on why we are using List.makeNode, where that is stored, and why it is being implemented this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, it's an error.

```
function List(){
    List.makeNode = function(){ };
    /* */
}
List.makeNode;    // undefined
new List();       // This creates List.makeNode method
List.makeNode;    // function
new List();       // This recreates List.makeNode method
```

There is no point in resetting a method of the constructor each time an instance is created (except if you want to have access to data of last created instance, which is not the case).

If `makeNode` really should be a `List` method, a better approach would be

```
function List(){
    /* */
}
List.makeNode = function(){ };
```

Or, if it should be a privileged method of instances,

```
function List(){
    this.makeNode = function(){ };
    /* */
}
```

Or, if it should be public method of instances,

```
function List(){
    /* */
}
List.prototype.makeNode = function(){ };
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is makeNode a property/method on the List Object which also contains the List Function?

It's only a property on the `List` function. Every function is an object, so you can assign properties to a function just like you can do with every other object.

But putting the assignment inside the constructor is strange an unnecessary. "Static methods" should just be assigned to the constructor once it was created:

```
function List () {
  // ...
}

List.makeNode = function() {
   // ...
};
```

> Why do we have to keep makeNode associated with List?

What would you do instead? You could just define a standalone function, like `function makeNode() { ... }`, but since the function is only used for creating lists, it makes sense to associate it with `List` somehow.

> Is it a big deal to change List to 'this' and have the makeNode function on every new instance of 'List()'?

It means that **every** instead of `List` has their own *copy* of `makeNode`. Since the function itself does not depend on any instance specific properties, doing that would just be unnecessary.

You *could* assign the method to `List.prototype` instead, but still, it doesn't look like a `List` instance needs access to that function, so there is no reason to put it there.

Comment: +1, though you could emphasize a bit more that "the List Object" *is* "the List Function" which he speaks of

Comment: Personally I'd just make it a local function of the List constructor. There's no obvious reason for it to be externally visible. Making it a property of the constructor function seems like something done gratuitously for pedagogical reasons. Matter of opinion I guess.

Answer (score 0):

both answers are very good actually.

If I may add a bit to them, an easy way to create the class list would be like this

```
var List = (function () {
    function List() { /*Your Constructor*/ };
    List.prototype.add = function () { /*this is a method on each object*/ };
    List.makeNode = function() { /*Static method on Class List*/ };

})();

var myList = new List();
var myNode = List.makeNode();
/* Do something with the node */
myList.add(myNode);
```